# Is there a way to run an R code from an html UI?

Tags: javascript, html, r, flask

I've made an application using flask and html which needs to run an R code in the background. The fetching of input and output is handled by flask but I need to run the R code to calculate the output. Is there any function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the data to Flask (with HTML form or you can also use Javascript AJAX if needed)

then run your R code and get the output like this:(I don't know any thing about R this is an example):

python code:

`R_code_resault = os.popen(f'Rcompiler Rfile {arg1} {arg2}').read()`

you got arg1&2 from HTML in flask

then render an HTML template and pass the `R_code_resault` variable to it and then use it in suitable position and place using Jinja